# Unity changing components of different assets when a button is clicked

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am very new to Unity and c# in general but I currently have a game that has 2 different backgrounds, and I would like to figure out how to swap between the 2 backgrounds - LightBackground and NightBackground - when a button is clicked, with the default background being the LightBackground and when the button is clicked, the NightBackground is used. My idea was to change the order in layer (sortingOrder) of the NightBackground when the button is clicked but was very unsuccessful upon attempting many things.

At the moment I have made a Night/Dark script which I have placed in the button on-click and it changes the sortingOrder of the Nightbackground but how can i make it simultaneously change the sortingOrder of the LightBackground. In addition, currently i have a game object called Game Manager which is linked to the Gameover Canvas which displays the button I want and the replay button; but as soon as the button is clicked, the background does change but as soon as the replay button is clicked, the background goes back to the LightBackground.

**NightDark Script:**

```
public class NightDark : MonoBehaviour
{

    public GameObject NightBackground;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        NightBackground.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sortingOrder++;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

    }
}
```

**Game Manager Script:**

```
public class GameManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject gameOverCanvas;

    private void Start()
    {
        Time.timeScale = 1;
    }


    public void GameOver()
    {
        gameOverCanvas.SetActive(true);
        Time.timeScale = 0;
    }

    public void Replay()
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene(0);
    }
}
```

It may be easier to view the [Game Manager](https://codeshare.io/5vW1vl) and [NightDark](https://codeshare.io/5ZVRed) here.

If any of you could help in the slightest, it would be much appreciated since I am really struggling at the moment. Thanks again.

Comment: This is `c#` and not the deprecated JavaScript flavour called `unityscript`. Also this is not really directly related to `VisualStudio`

Comment: Oh really, sorry wasn't aware unityscript was something different. I assumed that because I used visual studio it might apply to that?.

Comment: Please read the tag descriptions carefully ;) `Use this tag if you have a specific question about Visual Studio features and functionality. DO NOT use this tag on questions regarding code which merely happened to be written in Visual Studio. Consider tagging the exact technology area your question links to and also tagging a more specific version of Visual Studio. Please mention your exact VS version, edition, and update level in your question. `

Answer (score 0):

What speaks against having **one single background** controller and rather only switch out the [`Sprite`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Sprite.html) you display in the backgrounds [`SpriteRenderer.sprite`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SpriteRenderer-sprite.html) property

```
public class BackgroundController : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Drag all these in via the Inspector
    [Header("References")]
    [SerielizeField] private SpriteRenderer backgroundRenderer;

    [Header("Assets")]
    [SerielizeField] private Sprite daySprite;
    [SerielizeField] private Sprite nightSprite;    

    // This is static so it keeps its value session wide also after
    // reloading the scene
    private static bool _isDay;

    private void Start()
    {
        // inverts the _isDay -> starts as day the first time
        SwitchBackground();
    }

    // This you call when the button is clicked
    public void SwitchBackground()
    {
        // invert the flag
        _isDay = !_isDay;

        // chose the new sprite according to the flag
        backgroundRenderer.sprite = _isDay ? daySprite : nightSprite;
    }
}
```

Comment: I see what you mean. Thanks, this seems like the better way to write the script. Just for clarification, I should place this script on which component?

Comment: Hmm, what should I put in the background renderer variable? Also, How should I assign it to the button?

Comment: any ideas about this?

Comment: This should be on any object in the scene but I would prefer the background ;) You only need one single background so either keep the light or dark background object and remove the other one. And then you drag in the according object that has the `SpriteRenderer` attached ...

Comment: Then for the button there are multiple ways and many tutorials online: e.g. [Via the Inspector](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kdkrjCF0KCo) or [via code](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JoMb2rbYEnk)

Comment: Right, the only problem now is that when i click the replay button in the Gameover Canvas - which is using the [Game Manager Script](https://codeshare.io/5vW1vl) - it ignores the button click and proceeds to return it to the original. Any ideas? @derHugo

Comment: Just for clarification, the button should only appear in the Gameover Canvas and when pressed will change the look of the game going forward after the replay button is clicked

Comment: well you are reloading the scene so everything is reloaded and has its default values ... from your question it wasn't clear that this happens at the same time as your background switch;) of course it is reset to `day` in this case. Rather make it `static` so it is isn't affected by a reload  .. see updated answer